# tcolorbox: manual page break

Tags: tcolorbox, page-breaking

I have some nested tcolorboxes that I would like to break. To achieve this I try to reproduce the 'faked freak' on page 424 of the tcolorbox manual, but without success. Here is a MWE with a simple box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
    enhanced, 
    title = Title,
    boxsep = 3mm,
    frame hidden,
    interior hidden,
    attach boxed title to top left = {yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    frame code = {\draw  (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) --(frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle;},
    skin first is subskin of = {emptyfirst}{frame code = {%
                  \draw  (frame.south west) -- (frame.north west) --(frame.north east) -- (frame.south east);}},
    skin middle is subskin of = {emptymiddle}{frame code={%
                  \draw  (frame.north west) -- (frame.south west) 
                         (frame.north east) -- (frame.south east);}},
    skin last is subskin of = {emptylast}{frame code={%
                  \draw  (frame.north west) -- (frame.south west) -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.north east);}},
    width = #2,
    #1}


\begin{document}
    %with tcolorbox breakable library: works (but won't with nested boxes)
    \begin{mybox}[breakable]{\linewidth}
        \lipsum[1]      
        
        \tcbbreak
        
        \lipsum[1]      
    \end{mybox}
    
    \pagebreak
    
    %with 'faked break':
    %draws no frame
    \begin{mybox}[skin = enhancedfirst]{\linewidth}
        \lipsum[1]      
    \end{mybox}

    \pagebreak

    %draws title again and no frame
    \begin{mybox}[skin = enhancedlast, breakable]{\linewidth}
        \lipsum[1]      
    \end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

If I don't define new skins, the 'faked break' works as expected. Why it doesn't work in the above code?